# Does ATI Mobility Radeon HD 6370 support OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

Can I do OpenCL programming with these hardware specs?

**CPU:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU M480 @ 2.67GHz

**Graphics:** ATI Mobility Radeon HD 6370

**RAM:** 4GB

**OS:** Windows 7 Service Pack 1

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We expect everybody to do some research before asking questions here. Can you present us with what you've found out so far or how you've been looking for that information?

Comment: Searching "opencl hardware support" turned up a lot of [useful results](http://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2011-12-29/opencl-hardware-support/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes that setup will support development up to OpenCL 1.1 according to the AMD website.

The specs were quite clearly documented on the [AMD website](http://www.amd.com/us/products/notebook/graphics/amd-radeon-6000m/amd-radeon-6300m/Pages/amd-radeon-6300m.aspx#2).